# issue with Redirect To React Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-routing

Below is my code of a functional component in react, where I am setting up the route based on the userLoggedIn status.

```
let routes;

  if (user.loggedIn === true) {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/UserProfiles" component={UserProfiles} />
        <Route path="/EditProfile/" component={EditUserProfile} />
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>      
    )
  }
  else{
    routes = (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/Signup" component={SignUp} />
      <Redirect to="/" />
    </Switch> 
    )
  }
```

In the return function of my component, I have included this route as:

```
 return (    
        ...
        {routes}   
        ...    
  );
```

Everything is working fine, the only issue I am facing is when the user is loggedIn and navigates to the urls: 'localhost:3000/UserProfiles' or, 'localhost:3000/EditProfile/' by directly entering in the browser. They are redirected to Home component due to `<Redirect to="/" />`.
I don't understand why Redirect is not working for the valid paths.

Comment: My guess is that when a user is directly navigating to a page, like a fresh page load, that maybe `use.loggedIn` hasn't loaded yet(redux state?), but this is just a hunch based on what little bit of code you've shared. If `user.loggedIn` is falsey, then your other routes are returned and there aren't any matches and the redirect wins out.

Comment: @DrewReese Your comment solved the issue. You are right. The redirect is happening because user.loggedIn is falsey initially. Thanks!